# Please explain the antiderivative

Tags: integration

Can someone please explain what an antiderivative is. Is there a rule for finding the general antiderivative of a function?

Comment: An anti-derivative for a function $f(x)$ is a function $F(x)$ such that $\frac d{dx} F(x)=f(x)$.  Any two antiderivatives differ by an additive constant.  That is, if $F(x),G(x)$ are both antiderivatives then $G(x)=F(x)+c$ for some constant $c$.  There is no general method for finding them in closed form, but there are generally useful numerical methods for approximating them.

Comment: Please do some research before asking; pick up *any* elementary calculus book, or read the Wikipedia article. Then ask a focused and specific question that's not just "explain this broad topic to me." Voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An antiderivative of a function $f$, with domain $D$, is a function $F$, with domain $D$, such that $\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in D$. If $F$ and $G$ are antiderivatives for $f$, then $F(x)=G(x)+C$ for all $x\in D$ and for some constant $C$. One can find the family of antiderivatives (which contains all antiderivatives, where they only differ by a constant) by computing the indefinite integral of $f$:
$$\int f(x)dx=F(x)+C\qquad\text{$C$ is a constant}$$
provided $f$ is integrable of course.